# Showing that $f(x)/x$ is decreasing on $[0, \infty) $

Tags: real-analysis

I want to prove that if $f:[0, \infty) \to [ 0, \infty )$,$f(0)=0$ and $f(x)>0$ for all $x>0$, $f$ is increasing and $f'$ is decreasing then $f(x)/x$ is decreasing for $x>0$.

Here's my attempt:
Let $x,y \in (0, \infty)$ and suppose that $x\le y$. By the mean value theorem, we have that $f(x)/x=f'(c)$ and $f(y)/y=f'(d)$ for some $c \in (0, \infty)$ and some $d \in (0, \infty)$. If we show that $c\le d$, we'll be done because then $f'(d)\le f'(c)$, i.e., $f(y)/y \le f(x) /x$. So assume that $d<c$. Then $f'(c) \le f'(d)$.

I haven't been able to proceed from here. Hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A slight modification of your idea works: For $0 < x < y$ use the mean-value theorem not on the intervals $[0, x]$ and $[0, y]$, but on $[0, x]$ and $[x, y]$. Then
$$
 \frac{f(x)}{x} = f'(c) \, , \, \frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x} = f'(d)
$$
with $c \in (0, x)$ and $d \in (x, y)$, so that $f'(c) \ge f'(d)$. It follows that
$$
 \frac{f(x)}{x}  \ge \frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}
$$
which is equivalent to $\frac{f(x)}{x} \ge \frac{f(y)}{y}$.

---

Another option is to use that a function with decreasing derivative is *concave,* so that for $0 < x < y$
$$
f(x) \ge \frac{y-x}{y}f(0) + \frac{x}{y}f(x) = \frac{x}{y}f(y) \, .
$$

Comment: I think I had almost completed the problem using the first idea. (I didn't post that attempt here.) Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 2):

$f(x)=\int_0^{x} f'(t)dt \geq \int_0^{x} f'(x)dt =xf'(x)$. Hence $\frac d {dx} (\frac {f(x)}x )=\frac {xf'(x)-f(x)} x \leq 0$ and this implies that $\frac {f(x)}x$ is decreasing.

Comment: I was thinking along those lines too but I couldn't get it. Thanks.